# libCURL timeout while receiving HTTP multi-part flow

Tags: c++, timeout, libcurl

I'm using [libCURL](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) to perform an HTTP GET request toward a device that responds with a continuous flow of data in a multipart HTTP response.

I'd like to handle the unfortunate but possible case where the device is disconnected/shutdown or is not reachable anymore on the network.
By default libCURL does not have a few seconds timeout as I need, so I tried:

1. setting the CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT options,
   but this only works at connection stage, not while already receiving data.
2. setting the [CURLOPT_TIMEOUT](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMEOUT.html) option,
   but this seems to always ***force*** a timeout even when data is still received.

My question is: how can I properly handle a timeout with libCURL, in the case described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your scenario instead of

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, <your timeout in seconds>);
```

use

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, <your timeout in seconds>);
```

The above two lines make sure that if the average speed drops below 1 byte per second, in a time frame of X seconds, then the operation is aborted (timeout).

See [reference here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME.html).